# How do I move a geographic map during a pressAndHold event in a Qt application?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

There is a program that transmits latitude and longitude in `"Line Edit"`. But at the same time the opportunity to move the card is lost. How do I make the map move behind the mouse during the pressAndHold event?

places_map.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6

Rectangle {
    id: rect
    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "osm" // "mapboxgl", "esri", ...
        // specify plugin parameters if necessary
        // PluginParameter {
        //     name:
        //     value:
        // }
    }


    Map {
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: mapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.91, 10.75) // Oslo
        zoomLevel: 14
    }

    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked:  lineEdit.text = ""+ map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y))
    }
}
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->quickWidget->rootContext()->setContextProperty("lineEdit", ui->lineEdit);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: @ eyllanesc Oh hello, this is your program. How do I move the area of the geographic map to the mouse track?

Comment: you want to move the map when you press and drag the mouse?

Comment: @ eyllanesc Yes exactly. Sorry I can not get used to that English speakers are always clarified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to move the map is to use gesture as I show below:

```
Map {
    [...]
    gesture.enabled: true
    gesture.acceptedGestures: MapGestureArea.PanGesture
}
```

But when using the `MouseArea` it blocks these actions, so we can create the same effect using `onPressed` and `onPositionChanged`:

```
MouseArea{
    anchors.fill: parent

    property int lastX : -1
    property int lastY : -1

    onPressed : {
        lastX = mouse.x
        lastY = mouse.y
    }

    onPositionChanged: {
        map.pan(lastX-mouse.x, lastY-mouse.y)
        lastX = mouse.x
        lastY = mouse.y
    }
    onClicked:  lineEdit.text = ""+ map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y))
}
```

Comment: I have gesture.enabled=true; everything works great but the map doesn't start panning as soon as I press and move the mouse pointer instead the map start panning when the mouse pointer move about 10-20px across screen. Can you please mention a solution for this?

Comment: I have posted the Question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60136395/4435650 It would be so nice if you can help. Thank you!